# Saving port 9600 datas in given time

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, port, listen

I'm using Arduino and getting values from my shields and sensors. And also I send some of them to serial.println because of listening port 9600. I'm listening port 9600 and save these values to txt. After that I upload these values to database and use web services.

But I couldn't save the 9600 port in given time. Because if I didn't close the python application, it never close and never save txt file.

My code is below. I want to save txt for every 1 minutes.

How can I do it?

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600, timeout=1)
while 1:
    line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
    line2=line.decode("utf-8")
    ths = open("/Users/macproretina//Desktop/data.txt", "a")
    ths.write(line2)
ser.close()
```

Comment: just add ths.close() below ser.close()

Comment: but, how can I define time for it?

Comment: Give the file a name based on the start time perhaps? That would make a unique filename each time it runs.

Comment: ı just want to close this program running after given time. but don't know how to do it.

Comment: So your goal is to have a program that runs for one minute, writing data from serial to a file, and then terminate?

Comment: yeah, exactly. you mean what i wrote before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple timer to stop the loop. I cleaned up the resource management a bit, context managers are really useful.

```
import threading
from contextlib import closing
import serial

continue_looping = True
def stopper():
    global continue_looping
    continue_looping = False

timer = threading.Timer(60, stopper)
timer.start()

with open("/Users/macproretina/Desktop/data.txt", 'w') as out_file:
    with closing(serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1411', 9600, timeout=1)) as ser:
        while continue_looping:
            line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
            out_file.write(line.decode('utf-8')
            out_file.flush()
```

It might be off a bit due to serial timeouts. Notice that you get the output written to the file if you call `f.flush()` in case you need that.

Comment: it gives an error as below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial-reader.py", line 17, in <module>
    out_file.write(line)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

Comment: you need to decode the data from serial. I've updated my answer and the tags of your question

Comment: it gives an error as below now. i think it terminates the program when it starts but couldn't solve it.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serial-reader.py", line 16, in <module>
    line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 460, in read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)')
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected?)

Comment: Can you check with your original program if the arduino sends any data?

Comment: the program works but it closes although i don't want. for examle i get 2-3 value, after that it crash.

Comment: So it's probably your arduino, sorry I can't help you there, I don't own one.

Comment: yes but i only send serial.println("123456") in loop. so there can't be any problem with it.